# Retrieving image captured from external storage using Glide v4 not working?

Tags: android, android-glide

My problem is that when I try to capture an image and try to display the full-size image from the phone (api level 28) to the imageview using Glide v4 it returns as empty while when in the emulator it functions properly. I followed the official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics#TaskPath) and tried using Glide to display the image. I have also checked if the phone saves the image and the screenshot is shown below where it is there but somehow the app cannot retrieve the image via Uri.

This is my **onActivityResult()**

```java
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE_1 &&
                resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (data != null) {
                Glide.with(this)
                        .load(currentPhotoPath)
                        .into(imageView1);
            }
        }
            Log.d("result","Current photo path:"+currentPhotoPath);

    }
```

**This is the log result for current path**

```
2019-12-01 19:59:04.754 32120-32120/com.example.croppingimage D/result: Current photo path:/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.croppingimage/files/Pictures/JPEG_191201_195849_7894051887248641546.jpg
```

**Screenshot is taken from the emulator**
[image]

**Screenshot is taken from phone.**
[image]

Comment: Forgot to add the images. I've edited it now.

Comment: I've edited the question again so as to further clarify that capturing the image is the source and trying to display the full-size image onto imageview to the phone is needed.

Comment: okay I've edited it to remove the unnecessary code and kept the images and onActivityResult()

Comment: Log.d("result", "currentPhotoPath: " + currentPhotoPath);

Comment: Okay I've edited the post and added the log result

Comment: You should log before calling Glide. And use the File class to check if the file exists and wich size it has using File.exists() and File.length(). Please add the code here too. Also use File.canRead().